# AOSP - how to get final contents of PRODUCT_PACKAGES while building

Tags: android, android-source, android-build, android-soong, android-make

Different packages and components we can add via PRODUCT_PACKAGES tag in different mk files. I want to remove some unwanted packages while building AOSP for my target.

But for some packages this is not working as I am unable to find from which location there even being added and for some I do not want to modify those original source files (in the actual codebase there are multiple vendors/teams as such)

is there any way to see the complete PRODUCT_PACKAGES content while building AOSP?

I am using below for removing the unwanted packages :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

MY_OVERRIDE_PACKAGES := \
Dialer \
Calendar \
etc

LOCAL_MODULE := override_packages
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
PACKAGES.$(LOCAL_MODULE).OVERRIDES := $(strip $(MY_OVERRIDE_PACKAGES))
include $(BUILD_PHONY_PACKAGE)
```

Comment: Looks like a Phony module with the overrides is the way to remove packages as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57386273/12519442


To find what files are adding these, you could try the `mgrep PACKAGE` command (after running the `envsetup.sh` which should search the Makefiles and .bp files for your package to see where it comes from.


You can also check the `installed-files.txt` files inside the output folder, `out/target/product/your_device/installed-files.txt`

Comment: yes, I am indeed using the phony module, the problem is I need to see it while building or maybe before building, But I don't think there is an easy way for this.